# Computer Monitor Buzzing

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I just setup a RPi 3 with Raspbian, but I am getting a buzzing through my monitor.  It is connected via an HDMI to DVI cable.  When I turn off the monitor the buzzing stops.  The monitor does not have any speakers.  Here is the OS info:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"<br/>
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"<br/>
VERSION_ID="8"<br/>
VERSION="8 (jessie)"<br/>
ID=raspbian
```

Comment: Can you try the monitor with a different computer to see if it still buzzes?

Answer (score 0):

I turned up the brightness on my monitor and the buzzing stopped

Comment: I really don't see how this can help anyone (unless of course you're going to sell your screen soon ;)

Comment: It is a common issue for LCD monitors to buzz when the brightness is turned down too far.  So it may help others.  I only noticed it with my Pi because my other computer was so loud it hid the hum.

Comment: It may also be the humming only started recently; it is supposedly because of [capacitor degredation](https://www.devside.net/blog/lcd-making-a-buzzing-noise) which is why turning the brightness up alters the frequency (then you can't hear it any more).  I had one that started to do this after 5-6 years, and a few months later that's all it did (quite loudly, no picture, may or may not be the same cause...).